# Using \b in replaceAll regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, replaceall

I want to replace a text in a string which matches a given pattern. I wrote below Java code to do that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         /* Block 1 */
         String s1="123 Test Testing";
         System.out.println(s1.replaceAll("\\bTest\\b", "<Replaced with Test Message>")); // Prints 123 <Replaced with Test Message> Testing


        /* Block 2 */
        String s2="123 Test] Test]ing";
        System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("\\bTest\\]\\b", "<Replaced with Test Message>")); //Prints 123 Test] <Replaced with Test Message>ing

    }
```

First block is working as expected. But in second block, instead of replacing `Test]` present in the beginning of the string, it's replacing part of `Test]ing`.

Is there anything wrong in the code or regex?
How to match `Test]` instead of `Test]` of `Test]ing`

Comment: All correct (no issues at all with your regexps, they work as expected). I think you need to use `"(?<!\\S)Test\\](?!\\S)"`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Updated the code. With this code, your solution is failing.

Comment: What do you mean by "failing"? My suggestion works perfectly - https://regex101.com/r/w1wXqd/1

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew. But how come the same regex is not working in javascript?

Comment: Because the regex is not compatible with the JavaScript regex engine. Your question is tagged with JAVA.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It's k. I was trying to give the best solution to end user. So I was trying Javascript as well. But not required now. Thanks.

Comment: When downvoting the question, Please mention the reason as well. So that people won't make the same mistake again. Currently, I don't know why I got a downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The \b in your regex matches a word-boundary, i.e. a position between a word \w and a non-word \W character. Since the ] in your pattern is a non-word character, a word-boundary does not exist in the first position (Test] ) with the following space, but in the second position (Test]ing) where the ] is followed by the word character i.

To match the first Test] you could change your regex to

```
"\\bTest\\]\\B"
```

to match a non-word boundary after the ].

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove regex from the second block than it was work fine. :)

```
System.out.println(s2.replaceAll("Test\\]", "<Replaced with Test Message>")); //Prints Test] <Replaced with Test Message>ing
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   <Replaced with Test Message> <Replaced with Test Message>ing
```

Comment: Please read the question. I have to match Test] which is present in the beginning of the string. Not the part of some word.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` is a [word boundary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html) in Java regular expression.
It works for words that contain only "[any lowercase letter, any uppercase letter, the underscore character, or any digit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pre_char_classes.html)", ie [a-zA-Z_0-9]
According that **Test]** is not a word and `\b` cannot work for it.